# Xamarin iOS produce random crash

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin iOS from last 3 weeks, before this i am using objective c and swift for developing native iOS apps.
What actually happened is very rare, i never seen this type of issue in native iOS.
Let suppose there are two view controllers FirstVC and SecondVC, and there are some outlets defined in storyboard for both of them. Now i am navigating(Push) from FirstVC to SecondVC vice-versa(Pop). After doing this 5 to 6 times, in any of view controller i get a crash and when i debug it, what i found is something rare(please see attached image), the label has an instance but properties of label like text, frame, color, background nothing can be accessible and when i am setting something on this property it produces SIGSEGV error.

Because of this, my application is getting crash after every 3 to 4 minutes of usage.

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BhW4.png)

In attached image, one label has this issue whereas other have all its properties.

**Note:** It is not because of memory management.

Comment: Did the label create via the storyboard or code?

Comment: it is created by storyboard.

Comment: Will this issue happen if you create the label via C# code?

Comment: I don't try that..but i think this issue not happen when i create label via code..

Comment: Maybe it's a bug with xamarin storyboard, you may file a bug here:https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/.